# Popup abrindo em toda página após terminar o Load, mesmo depois de ser fechado

Tags: jquery, localstorage, popup, load

Galera tenho uma seguinte situaçã: Um Popup aparece toda vez que termina um load na página, o usuário pode clicar X (fechar). Porém toda vez que ele entra em outra página o Popup sobe novamente e assim fica chato pro usuário ter que ficar fechando sempre.
Alguém consegue me ajudar numa solução. Help

```
$(window).load("document", function(){
  setTimeout(() => {
      $("#whats-help").slideDown()
  }, 2000)
})  // Inicia sempre após a página terminar de carregar.


$("#whats-close").click(function(){
  $("#whats-help").slideToggle(500);
})
```

Comment: Tem que fazer um localStorage

Comment: Tem idéia como faço com Jquery mano, no click de fechar?

Comment: Já dei a dica ai acima man, agora é só vc pesquisar

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isshow = localStorage.getItem('isshow');
  if (isshow== null) {
    localStorage.setItem('isshow', 1);

    // Show popup here
    $('#jPopup').show();
  }
});
```